# Upgrading Artifactory from 2.3.3.1 to 4.14.3 without Export/ Import

Tags: upgrade, artifactory

We're currently using Artifactory 2.3.3.1 and want to upgrade to V 4.14.3
As per the findings on web the usual approach is a 2 phase upgrade i.e
 V 2.3.3.1 ->> V 3.9 ->> V 4.14

I'm aware of the steps mentioned in the JFrog documentation but the issue is over the time the current artifactory has grown in size in TBs. It's not feasible to do an export and Import which as per documentation is one of the steps of upgrading from V 2.3.3.1 ->> V 3.9.

Is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade from 2.6.7 to 3.x without exporting the artifacts. Take a look at the "Upgrading from v2.6.7 and Above to v3.x" section of the [upgrade instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Upgrading+Artifactory). Notice that you check the "Exclude Content" checkbox, which means you will only export the metadata and not the artifacts themselves.
You can upgrade from 2.3.3.1 to 2.6.7 using the regular upgrade procedure, without the need to export data.
One thing you **must** assure is having a **full backup** of Artifactory before starting this procedure!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Read this while going trough the documentation but tried directly from V2.3.3.1 where Exclude content forces exclude metadata. As suggested by you upgraded 2.3.3.1 -> 2.6.7 -> 3.9.5 -> 4.14.5 . Thanks :)